# Запустить REST-API на Golang в Minikube

Tags: golang, docker, rest, minikube

Есть REST-API на Go. По тз надо все запустить в Minikube и использовать Traefik для роутинга.
https://github.com/gh0st3e/REST-API_Innowise/tree/dev - вот само приложение

Также есть бд Postgress основная и для тестов.

Можете рассказать вообще что нужно сделать и с чего вообще начать.

Comment: читать доку traefik и посмотреть примеры.  и посмотреть как запускать миникуб

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Случайно удалил ответ на твой вопрос, если можешь помочь, глянь пожалуйста этот вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1466596/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-go-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-minikube-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-traefik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем пришлось разобраться во всем самому, поэтому дам краткий гайд, как все это сделать (кроме Traefik, его так и не получилось подключить)

***1. Docker***

Для начала устанавливаем DockerDesktop

- https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/

Далее нам наше приложение надо запихнуть в контейнер, мое приложение было с бд, поэтому буду показывать с ней.

***1.1. Dockerfile***

Чтобы наше приложение запихнуть в контейнер, надо рассказать докеру как это сделать. Для это в корне приложения создаем файл с название ***Dockerfile***

В этом файле нам нужно описать, что будет делать докер с нашим приложением и как ему создать контейнер. Для разных проектов содержимое этого файла может быть разное (далее буду называть это конфигом)

Вот пример моего конфига

```
FROM golang:alpine AS builder

ADD . /src
RUN cd /src && go build -o main.bin cmd/main.go

FROM alpine as runner

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /src/main.bin /app/

ENTRYPOINT ./main.bin

CMD ["/app"]
```

Если кратко и понятно. Здесь мы указываем откуда взять наш проект, Docker сам все это себе скачает, также установит зависимости из go.mod.

(Уже из этого можно создать контейнер, но я не помню команду)

***1.2. docker-compose***

Так как мое приложение работает с базой данных, то мне также нужно создать контейнер с моей базой данных.

Для этого воспользуемся docker-compose.

В корне приложения создаем файл ***docker-compose.yaml***

В нем мы укажем конфиги для создания контейнеров для приложения и для бд.

Вот содержимое моего компоуза:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "db_name"
      POSTGRES_USER: "db_user"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "db_password"
      PGDATA: "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - ./db/init.sql.:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql
  app:
    image: appimage
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
      target: runner
    expose:
      - 8081
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/app
volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
```

Как и в случае с Dockerfile, конфиги могут быть разные, но этот самый простой.

Хочу обратить внимание на строку:

```
- ./db/init.sql.:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql
```

Она нужна нам для миграции базы данных. В моем случае миграция выполнена очень просто, я просто говорю докеру, что нужно после создания контейнера запустить скрипт, где я создаю свою таблицу.

Это путь к моему скрипту:

```
./db/init.sql
```

Это нужно прописать, чтобы докер запустил скрипт

```
.:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql
```

***1.3. ***Создание контейнеров******

!! Перед создание контейнеров, если вы используете бд, поменяйте строку подключения, где в качестве ip укажите имя сервиса, в моем случае это bd!!!

Вот пример моей строки для локального подключения и для подключения внутри докера.

```
connStr := "user=your_user password=your_password dbname=your_db_name sslmode=disable" // Local DB
connStr := "postgres://yout_user:yout_password@db:5432/your_db_name?sslmode=disable" // Minikube DB
```

То что идет после знака @, там и нужно указать имя сервиса, порт вроде как можно не указывать, но лишним не будет

После того как вы все сконфигурировали можно запускать.

При первом запуске воспользуемся командой

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Эту команду также нужно использовать, если вы внесли какие-либо изменения в свой проект и хотите пересоздать свои контейнеры.

В ином случае можно воспользоваться командой

```
docker-compose up -d
```

В результате выполнения команды в докере должны появиться два контейнера, объединенные в одну группу.

Далее в браузере или в Postman можно прописать адрес localhost:8081/'yourquery' и получить доступ к вашему приложения, которое теперь запущено в докере. Порт естественно нужен тот который вы указали в конфиге docker-compose

***1.4. DockerHub***

(Здесь будем работать уже не с контейнерами а с имэджами)

Для дальнейшей работы с Minikube нам нужно, чтобы наши имэджи где-то хранились. Для этого создаем учетную запись заходим на сайт

- https://hub.docker.com/

После регистрации прописываем в командной строке

```
docker login
```

Вводим логин и пароль которые указали при регистрации. Теперь у нас есть хранилище наших имэджей.

Теперь чтобы загрузить наши имэджи в докер хаб нужно сначала выдать им тэг, а затем запушить их.

Это выполняется с помощью команд:

```
docker tag 'your_image_name' 'your_login'/'your_image_name':'verison'
```

Думаю тут все понятно, единственное хочу обратить внимание что, нам нужно именно название имэджа а не контейнера. на пример моего приложения для бд я использова версию: "15-alpine", а для приложения "latest". Ну и когда будете писать команду кавычки не нужны, это для примера. В результате выполнения команды в DockerDesktop должно измениться название имэджа.

Теперь если у вас, например, как и у меня бд и приложения и вы протэгали и то и то, самое время запушить все на докер хаб. Тут все просто

```
docker push 'your_login'/'your_image_name':'verison'
```

После всей проделанной работы в вашем DockerHub должны появиться имэдж или имэджи, которые вы запушили.

***2. Minikube***

Плавно переходим к миникубу. Для работы с ним нужно устнавить сам миникуб, а также kubectl. В официальной документации вы найдете все необходимое, там отлично все разжовано.

- https://kubernetes.io/ru/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/

***2.1. Начало работы с minikube***

После установки у вас скорее всего будет запущен кластер миникуба, но если нет воспользуйтесь командой:

```
minikube start
```

По умолчанию он создастся в вашем докере, но его также можно запустить и в VirtualBox, и в других похожих приложения, по этой теме в интернете куча информации, поэтому задерживаться на этом не буду.

Далее пропишем команду

```
minikube status
```

Она должна нам показать что все хорошо и все процессы запущены.

Следующее что-нам предстоит сделать, это сменить докер в миникубе, после запуска миникуб пользуется нашими имэджами, которые расположены на вашем пк, а надо чтобы он пользовался имэджами внутри своего докера. Для этого выполним команду

```
minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression
```

Это команда для Windows, для линукса ее довольно легко найти в интернете.

После применения команды проверим, что теперь миникуб использует свой собственный докер. Выполним команду:

```
docker images
```

В результате мы должны получить список контейнеров, в числе которых не должны быть контейнеры, которые мы создали в пункте первом.

(В основном там будут контейнеры в имени которых будет содержаться k8s)

***2.2. Пул имэджей из DockerHub***

Теперь нам нужно запулить в наш миникуб имэджи, которые мы закинули на DockerHub.

Тут все просто. Воспользуемся командой

```
docker pull 'your_login'/'your_image_name':'verison'
```

После этого в списке контейнеров (docker images) должны появиться, те которые мы загрузили в докер хаба.

***2.3. Конфиги для подов minikube***

Теперь будем создавать поды в minikube. Для этого нам нужно создать конфиги для деплоймента и сервиса (надеюсь вы немного ознакомились с теорией и мне не нужно объянсять что это такое)

На самом деле, конфиги я создавал не самостоятельно, потому что это показалось для меня очень сложным. Но я нашел оптимальное решение. Я нашел тулл, которые автоматические создаст эти конфиги из вашего файла docker-compose. Вам всего-то нужно установить библиотеку и она все сделает за вас. Там находится инструкция и думаю у вас не возникнет проблем с установкой. (У меня возникла но я пофиксил проблему по первый ссылке в гугле)

После создания конфигов их нужно применить в миникубе.

Но перед этим хочу сказать, что у меня возникли некоторые трудности при миграции бд в миникубе. Поэтому если вы не найдете другого решения, а сделать надо позарез, предлагаю свое решение.

Так как миграция в миникубе не срабатывала, я решил прописать кусочек кода, который запускает скрипт создания таблицы через приложение. То есть в начале работы приложения запускается функция в которой находится скрипт.

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...

Да это костыль, и я не рекомендую так делать, если у вас достаточно времени чтобы решить эту проблему. В любом случае если времени осталось очень мало, этот способ рабочий и может вас спасти.

Возвращаемся к созданию подов.

После того как устанвоили библиотеку прописываете команду

```
kompose convert -f docker-compose.yaml
```

У вас должны появиться новые файлы с разрешением yaml. Это ваши конфигурационные файлы для миникуба.

В моем случае для бд и для приложения создалось по три файла (PersistentVolume, Deployment, Service)

Теперь нам нужно их применить, для этого по очереди прописываем команды

```
kubectl apply -f your_filename.yaml
```

Теперь проверим наши поды, и для этого воспользуемся командой:

```
kubectl get pods
```

Если ваши поды находятся в состоянии Running, значит скорее всего вы уже все сделали.

Если же нет, то придется искать ошибку и в этом случае вам помогут команды:

```
kubectl logs 'pod name'
kubectl describe pod 'pod name'
```

***2.3. Проверяем работу***

Если же у вас все хорошо и все поды в состоянии Running, осталось только запустить приложение.

Для этого воспользуемся командой:

```
minikube service app --url
```

Где app это имя вашего сервиса для приложения. Проверить имя можно командой (kubectl get services)

Вывод этого сообщения - это адрес, по которому мы будем обращаться к приложению. Например: http://localhost:12345

Все что вам остается сделать - это указать этот адрес в Postman или в браузере и можете отправлять запросы также как вы делали это на локальном компьютере.

***3. Финал***

В завершении хочу сказать, что это частное решение, и вряд ли оно подойдет абсолютно каждому, но в любому случае я описал всю суть работы, и надеюсь это вам поможет.

Можете ознакомиться с моим приложением и посмотреть содержимое описанных файлов и саму структуру проекта на гитхабе

- https://github.com/gh0st3e/REST-API_Innowise

Также я не могу сказать, что я сделал все правильно, но это работает и в крайнем случае может быть полезно для вас.

Удачного вката!!!